# isotop jquery animation not working?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, easing

I have isotop jquery pluging,
I have written js like,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
    layoutMode : 'masonry',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
               queue: false
           }
      });
  });
```

when I change the value of easing from 'linear' to 'swing' there are no change in effect,
how can I change it ?
and my second question is that

how many and which animation type (easing) supported by isotop jquery ?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filtering is working and there is no animation make sure that you are including the css provided in Isotope docs.

[Isotop docs for css animations](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html)